# Importing from node_modules in Sass Files (build using ng-cli)

Tags: angular, angular2-cli

I am using the `ng-cli` build tool to assemble my Angular2 application.

I am using Sass to style my components. Within these sass files I would like to import some sass content from bootstrap.

I have achieved this by using a Sass `@import` using a relative path to the relevant bootstrap files underneath `node_modules`:

```
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss";
```

This is a bit cumbersome, and breaks if I change the directory structure of my components.

Is there a neater mechanism to import form `node_modules` without the relative path?

---

It seems like the sass property [`includePaths`](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#includepaths) would allow me to state `node_modules` as an include path, and allow me to have the succinct import

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss";
```

How can I instruct `ng-cli` to configure Sass with `includePaths`?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding @import "~bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss" in your styles.scss

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for your help. You might want to make your answer even better by adding some explanation.